# Address arithmetic using a static buffer

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

```
#define ALLOCSZE 1000  


static char allocbuf[ALLOCSZE]; /* storage for alloc */
static char *allocp=allocbuf;     /* next free position */

char *alloc(int n) /* return pointer to n characters */
{
    if(allocbuf+ALLOCSZE-allocp>=n)
    {
        allocp +=n;
        return allocp-n;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Is size of allocbuf equal to size of char in the condition  `( if(allocbuf+ALLOCSZE-allocp>=n))`

Comment: Invalid code, that´s all to explain. If you can´t even make it compile... (and I´m not talking about the lack of main etc.)

Comment: allocbuf+ALLOCSZE-allocp>=n is bad. pointer+int+int (that is pointer, that is int) >= int this makes no sense

Comment: code seems has been copied from some TV movie

Comment: `THIS CODE IS FROM THE C PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE BRAIN W.KERNIGHAN DENNIS M. RITCHIE`. No. They know what case-sensitive etc. means. (pun intended :p)

Comment: Ok, now it looks better (at least the case sensitivity thing). But I still don´t get the question. You want to know the sizes of allocbuf, allocp and char? `sizeof(allocbuf)`, `sizeof(allocp)` and 1? And the condition is self-explaining.

Comment: @Exceptyon That is actually correct code. Arithmetic makes a lot of sense.

Comment: you completely changed the meaning of the question, including drastically changing the code snippet. I have rolled back your edit. If you wish you can ask a different question.

Comment: I can't ask a new question coz I m blocked for a while

Comment: @CroticParadox in this case you need accept your ban and try to improve yourself. Not to circumvent the ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sizeof(allocbuf) is equal to the size of the array which is 1000.

When `allocbuf` is used in the expression `allocbuf+ALLOCSZE-allocp>=n` it will decay to a char pointer, thus the pointer arithmetic will be correct.

When you run out of memory, your function will return 0.

I suggest that you change the return value to NULL and the type of function argument to size_t. And don't forget that the memory you get from your function alloc() can only be used for type `char`.

Comment: Indeed. Juggling the arithmetic slightly makes it more readable to my eye: `allocbuf+ALLOCSZE-allocp>=n` => `&allocbuf[ALLOCSZE]-allocp>=n` => `&allocp[n] <= &allocbuf[ALLOCSZE]`

Comment: @doynax Yes, I would write it the same minus the []: `allocp + n <= allocbuf + ALLOCSZE`